# Intercambiar el orden de creacion de Paneles

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms

Tengo un panel que a su vez tiene varios paneles en su interior y estos se generan dinámicamente, lo que estoy haciendo es que mediante el evento de mouse, tengo un menú que me permite intercambiar las posiciones de un panel con otro, es decir, si yo quiero intercambiar los lugares de PanelA con los de PanelB, PanelB toma la posición de PanelA y PanelA de PanelB, hasta ahora no hay problema.

El detalle que tengo es exportar la información de la colección de los Paneles secundarios a una hoja excel, estos salen como fueron creados, me imagino que por su Tabindex y lo que quiero es que si un panel intercambie posición con otro, en esta acción también intercambien el orden tal como fueron creados para que en el informe de Excel aparezcan en el orden en que están.

Estaba viendo la propiedad Panel.Controls.GetChildIndex y me arroja un valor, que imagino que es el índice con el que se crea, ¿es correcto? ¿Cómo puedo intercambiar el orden en que se crearon dentro de otro panel?

Intenté lo siguiente.

```
'Unidad Origen
Private Sub ToolStripMenuItem1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripMenuItem1.Click

    Dim clickedPanel = DirectCast(DirectCast(DirectCast(sender, ToolStripMenuItem).Owner, ContextMenuStrip).SourceControl, Panel)
    Dim varIndex As Integer = Panel1.Controls.GetChildIndex(clickedPanel)

    p1Name = clickedPanel.Name
    paParent = clickedPanel.Parent
    indexOrigen = clickedPanel.TabIndex

End Sub

'Unidad Destino
Private Sub ToolStripMenuItem2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStripMenuItem2.Click

    Dim clickedPanelDestino = DirectCast(DirectCast(DirectCast(sender, ToolStripMenuItem).Owner, ContextMenuStrip).SourceControl, Panel)

    p2Name = clickedPanelDestino.Name
    pbParent = clickedPanelDestino.Parent
    indexDestino = clickedPanelDestino.TabIndex

    Dim p1 = DirectCast(Panel1.Controls.Find(p1Name, True).FirstOrDefault(), Panel)
    If p1 Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentException("indexOrigen")
    Dim p2 = DirectCast(Panel1.Controls.Find(p2Name, True).FirstOrDefault(), Panel)
    If p2 Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentException("indexDestino")

    Dim temp = p2.Location
    Dim tempIndex = indexDestino
    p2.Location = p1.Location
    p2.TabIndex = p1.TabIndex
    p1.Location = temp
    p1.TabIndex = tempIndex
    
End Sub
```

¿Es correcto obtener el índice tal como se crearon y luego cambiar ese índice?

Si no es así, ¿cómo puedo realizar este cambio?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

**Despues de un tiempo, esta es mi solución.**

```
'Unidad Origen (Cut Option)
    Private Sub ToolStripMenuItem1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripMenuItem1.Click

        Dim clickedPanel = DirectCast(DirectCast(DirectCast(sender, ToolStripMenuItem).Owner, ContextMenuStrip).SourceControl, Panel)
        varIndexA = Panel1.Controls.GetChildIndex(clickedPanel)

        p1Name = clickedPanel.Name
        paParent = clickedPanel.Parent
        indexOrigen = clickedPanel.TabIndex

    End Sub

'Unidad Destino (Paste Option)
    Private Sub ToolStripMenuItem2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStripMenuItem2.Click

        Dim clickedPanelDestino = DirectCast(DirectCast(DirectCast(sender, ToolStripMenuItem).Owner, ContextMenuStrip).SourceControl, Panel)
        varIndexB = Panel1.Controls.GetChildIndex(clickedPanelDestino)
        p2Name = clickedPanelDestino.Name
        pbParent = clickedPanelDestino.Parent

        Dim p1 = DirectCast(Panel1.Controls.Find(p1Name, True).FirstOrDefault(), Panel)
        If p1 Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentException("indexOrigen")
        Dim p2 = DirectCast(Panel1.Controls.Find(p2Name, True).FirstOrDefault(), Panel)
        If p2 Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentException("indexDestino")

        Dim temp = p2.Location
        p2.Location = p1.Location
        Panel1.Controls.SetChildIndex(p2, varIndexA)
        p1.Location = temp
        Panel1.Controls.SetChildIndex(p1, varIndexB)

    End Sub
```

**Gracias**